# Необходимо написать многопользовательский сервер в kernel space

Tags: linux, c, kernel

Необходимо написать многопользовательский сервер в kernel space, но нет уверенности в том, какой из возможных подходов стоит использовать: workqueue, kthreads, tasklets или что-то иное. Если у вас есть опыт в этой сфере или вы знаете хорошие источники информации, отпишитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Напишите все три, потом отпрофилируйте. Никто не сможет сказать заранее.

Comment: Мне казалось, что люди опытные должны знать и понимать, какая технология и куда лучше всего подходит. Я новичок и некомпетентна в подобных вопросах.

Comment: Писать сервер kernel space - это превращать весь в сервер в нестабильную субстанцию. Используйте NETMAP, DPDK, PF_RING итп.